# Autogenerate alphanumeric ID

Tags: sql, vb.net, alphanumeric

Need help with autogenerate ID. I have this code that autogenerates ID but is only good up to 10 increments. It starts with `PO0001` and countinues up to `PO0010` only, once it gets to `PO0010` the ID gets stuck in `PO0001`.

here is the code I used:

```vb
Public Function newPOID(prefix As String, storedProcedure As String) As String

    Dim newId As String = prefix + "0001"
    Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = conString
    utos = New SqlCommand(storedProcedure, conn)
    utos.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    conn.Open()
    dr = utos.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then
        If dr.IsDBNull(0) Then
            Dim num As Integer = 1
            'Dim prefix As String = "PO"
            Dim append As String = prefix + num.ToString().PadLeft(4, "000")
            newId = append
        Else
            Dim POstring As String = dr(0).ToString.Substring(0, 3)
            Dim POID As Integer = dr(0).ToString.Substring(5) + 1
            Dim append As String = POstring + POID.ToString().PadLeft(3, "000")
            newId = append
        End If
        conn.Close()
    End If


    Return newId

End Function
```

Comment: You could always use an AutoIncrement column for the ID and Prepend "PO" to it for display.  If you are planning to generate the PK, dont do that.

Comment: @Plutonix I'll be using the autogenerated ID for a multiple row in SQL that's why I cant' use an autoincrement column. From listview, the data will be saved in the database using the autogenerated ID so that when I select the data using the ID I created, I can select multiple rows.

Comment: What does this data actually represent? It seems to me that you might be better using two tables, in which case you can simply let the database generate the IDs in both cases.  One row is added to the parent table and a single ID is generated, then multiple rows are added to the child table with the same parent ID.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  The data comes from a listview of purchases, with mulitple rows, from one customer or client and I'll be saving it in the database that's why I can't use the autoincrement column. I'm sorry but I'm having trouble with the language(English) please explain further what you mean..

Comment: Nothing you said there is a reason that you cannot use an auto-increment column.

Comment: the process is saving each row in the listview to the database with a column for the generated ID for the purpose that the transactions will be grouped as one. If an auto increment column is used then each row would have different ID although they belong to the same transaction. If there is a better way to do it, please do suggest.

Comment: the best way would be saving the PO# first before accepting transactions. if these will be cancelled then just mark the PO# as cancelled.  PO# number just masked the next number (auto).

Comment: @maSTArHiAn can you show me a sample code for the solution you suggested?

Comment: Hi, i no longer code vb but i am still a programmer/analyst. Here are steps. 1) button or menu to open PO window.  2) button that says create New PO (add new record code, if id is auto then you dont need to manually increment), save the new num as draft status. 3) mask the id with the proper PO presentation, refresh label after addnew 4) allow entry of transactions. 5) if the user choose to cancel then mark PO as cancelled otherwise accordingly. Goodluck.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn Thank you, I'm new at this but I'll try to figure out based  on the solution you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `num.ToString().PadLeft(4, "000")` with `Format(num,"000#)`